Can I optimize signal usage in Angular templates when using a getter?
I have a service that exposes a signal through a getter. The getter is used directly in the HTML template, but I am concerned about performance. Since Angular's change detection calls the getter on every re-render, I suspect this could lead to inefficiencies.
Here is my current implementation:
Service:
signal = signal();
getSignal() {
  return this.signal;
}

Template:
<h1>
  {{ service.getSignal()() }}
</h1>


My questions are:

Is it inefficient to use a getter in this context because it is recalculated on every re-render?
Can this issue be avoided by storing the signal in a class variable or another approach?
Does Angular optimize this internally, making this a non-issue?


You have no getter, a getter is get+space+name()
get Signal() {
  return this.signal;
}

Since by defect the variables in Angular are public you can use (always the service service was public) write in your component
{{service.signal()}}

If your service is private you can make a getter but in the component
get signalService()
{
    return this.service.signal()
}

And use
 {{signalService}}

Really, a getter have an infimus relevance in the performance

you can just use the signal in youre html and dont worry for the perfomentce its ok to use even if its was a real getter in youre case because its a signal the changed detection its better then the usual (if you use on push) you can read more about it in this articalenter link description here
